# Policy enforcement order?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using wso2 identity server 4.5.0 and i' m wondering whether there is the option to give priority to the enforcement of a policy instead of another. For instance, the action A to resource X must be prior to the action B to resource X.

Thanks in advance! 
Maria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you are asking about policy ordering... There can be multiple policies in the PDP policy store.  For each XACML request, PDP would pick the applicable policy (or policies) based on  policy’s  Target element. When more than one policy is applicable for the request. Then PDP needs to combine the results of all applicable policies based on the policy combining algorithm. Applicable polices are evaluated based on the order that they have defined. Order of polices can be configured using Identity Server management console.. I guess you can find on this using [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2013/10/27/multiple-policies-in-pdp-policy-ordering-and-combining/) blog post...